# Join Tables and totals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

How would I join the following tables to give a total count from all the tables.

```
select (BatchIdentifier),
       Count(distinct BatchIdentifier) as ERTBatchCheckIdentifier
from ERTBatchChecks 
Group By BatchIdentifier

select (ERTBatchNumber),
       Count(distinct ERTBatchNumber) as ERTBatchNumber
from ERTClaims
Group By ERTBatchNumber

select (BatchIdentifier),
       Count(distinct BatchIdentifier) as ERTBatchesIdentifier
from ERTBatches
Group By BatchIdentifier
```

Comment: Total count of what? All records, or groups, or...? Do BatchIdentifier and ERTBatchNumber have same values across tables, so the grouping should be across tables? Can you post some sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want a `SUM()` then use a derived table and `union all`:

```
SELECT Batch, SUM(Cnt) AS TotalCount
FROM (

    select (BatchIdentifier) AS Batch,
           Count(distinct BatchIdentifier) as Cnt
    from ERTBatchChecks 
    Group By BatchIdentifier

    union all

    select (ERTBatchNumber),
           Count(distinct ERTBatchNumber)
    from ERTClaims
    Group By ERTBatchNumber

    union all

    select (BatchIdentifier),
           Count(distinct BatchIdentifier)
    from ERTBatches
    Group By BatchIdentifier

   ) SubCounts
GROUP BY Batch
```

If you want a total count of the distinct 'batches' then use union and `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT Count(Batch) AS TotalDistinctBatches
FROM (

    select distinct BatchIdentifier as Batch
    from ERTBatchChecks

    union

    select distinct ERTBatchNumber
    from ERTClaims

    union

    select distinct BatchIdentifier
    from ERTBatches

   ) DistinctBatches
```

Note: `Union all` will keep duplicates, `Union` will not.  Hence for adding the counts, we want to use `Union all` in case two of the counts are the same.  But for counting the distinct batches, we want `Union` so we don't count the same batch more than once.

Comment: These are great but this is what I need. 999 (3) 666(3) 123 (2). So it would be the total of each identifier in all the column including the identifier in the results

Comment: @JohnMolina The first query should be close, I had left out the `BatchIdentifier` by mistake.  Which I called `Batch` for ease.